# Cloudera-on-azure. What is the default username and password for HUE?

Tags: azure, cloudera

I've deployed Cloudera on Azure using the provided [ARM template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/cloudera-on-centos/azuredeploy.json), now I'm poking around it. I can access the HUE login page on port 8888 on the master node however I don't what the username/password is. I've tried the defaultAdminusername ("azureuser") along with the password that I supplied at deploy-time but they're not working.
Does anyone know what the default username/password is for HUE? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you log in, you can put in any user name/password.  That account becomes the admin for Hue.

Comment: yeah, that's what I read somewhere but its not letting me in. Maybe I did something wrong initially and set an admin account without realising it, I'll spin another one up and have another go. Thanks again Paige.